# Howto remove a word from a Trie structure?

Tags: data-structures, haskell, trie

maybe I'm not smart enough to learn Haskell, but I'd give it the last chance.
I've got stuck at implementation of entry removal from a tree, Trie like structure to be a more specific (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

I'm looking for any advices (not a solution !) how to implement such pure function.
I've had an idea about one algorithm. Recreate a new tree by traversing whole tree "skipping" values equal to each character of the word, with edge condition return original tree if next character won't be found. But there arises a problem when a character also belongs to another word.

```
data Trie = Trie { commonness :: Maybe Int
                 , children :: [(Char, Trie)]
                 } deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

-- Creates an empty "dictionary"
trie :: Trie
trie = Trie { commonness = Nothing, children = [] }

-- Inserts a word with given commonness into dictionary
add :: String -> Int -> Trie -> Trie
add [] freq tree
    | (0 <= freq) && (freq <= 16) = tree { commonness = Just freq }
    | otherwise = error $ "Commonness out of bounds: " ++ (show freq)
add word freq tree = tree { children = traverse word (children tree) }
    where
        traverse [] tree = error $ "traverse called with [] " ++ (show tree)
        traverse (x:xs) [] = [(x, add xs freq trie)]
        traverse str@(x:xs) (t:ts)
            | x == fst t = (x, add xs freq $ snd t):ts
            | otherwise = t:(traverse str ts)

remove :: String -> Trie -> Trie
???
```

And the data looks like:

```
GHCi> putStrLn $ groom $ add "learn" 16 $ add "leap" 5 $ add "sing" 7 $ add "lift" 10 trie

Trie{commonness = Nothing,
     children =
       [('l',
         Trie{commonness = Nothing,
              children =
                [('i',
                  Trie{commonness = Nothing,
                       children =
                         [('f',
                           Trie{commonness = Nothing,
                                children = [('t', Trie{commonness = Just 10, children = []})]})]}),
                 ('e',
                  Trie{commonness = Nothing,
                       children =
                         [('a',
                           Trie{commonness = Nothing,
                                children =
                                  [('p', Trie{commonness = Just 5, children = []}),
                                   ('r',
                                    Trie{commonness = Nothing,
                                         children =
                                           [('n',
                                             Trie{commonness = Just 16, children = []})]})]})]})]}),
        ('s',
         Trie{commonness = Nothing,
              children =
                [('i',
                  Trie{commonness = Nothing,
                       children =
                         [('n',
                           Trie{commonness = Nothing,
                                children =
                                  [('g', Trie{commonness = Just 7, children = []})]})]})]})]}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is going to be easier if you use a `Map Char Trie` instead of `[(Char,Trie)]` for your child table.  That is what I'm going to assume for this answer.  I'll get you started with the inductive case:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map

remove :: String -> Trie -> Trie
remove (c:cs) t = t { children = Map.alter remove' c (children t) }
    where
    remove' (Just t) = Just (remove cs t)
    remove' Nothing = Nothing
remove [] t = ...
```

I'll leave the base case to you.  Here are the docs for the `Map` function I used, [alter](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Map.html#v%3aalter).  You could get this same solution without using `Map` if you implemented `alter` for `[(Char,a)]`.

*Exercise:* `remove'` is pretty wordy.  See if you can shorten it using `fmap`.

Comment: Anonymous Downvoter, please leave a comment explaining how this answer could be improved, or what I could do differently next time?  I would appreciate it.

Comment: This never actually removes nodes from the trie, does it? The base case sets the commonness of a node (representing a word) to zero, correct? But the node (and all intermediate nodes) remain in the trie. Not a clean solution, and possibly bad for performance (wasted space, slower lookup). Fix: `remove' (Just t)` should check the result node of `remove cs t` and return `Nothing` if the node is empty (commonness = 0, map is empty).

Comment: Also, using `Map.update` instead of `Map.alter` would make the code a little simpler: The case `remove' Nothing = Nothing` didn't do anything useful anyway, and the case `remove' (Just t) = ...` becomes `remove' t = ...`

Comment: Correction: I should have said `Nothing` instead of "zero" / "0".

Comment: @jcsahnwaldt, well it will actually remove nodes from the trie with the correct base case.  However, you're correct that intermediate nodes are not removed, a problem I hadn't noticed.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But... how can the base case remove nodes? We only get to the base case at the end of the string. The base case `remove [] t` might want to remove node `t` from its parent - but it can't. And removing any children of `t` wouldn't be correct. But maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: @jcsahnwaldt it doesn't need to be removed from it's parent to not exist.  There is another encoding of nonexistence in this representation (ostensibly, at least)

Comment: I guess by "ostensibly" you mean that `commonness` is `Nothing`, right? But in that sense, most intermediate nodes are 'nonexistent' as well. My point was that all these nodes will still 'physically' exist, taking up space and making queries slower: a query for a word that has been removed from the trie has to follow the chain of nodes to the end just to find that the leaf node doesn't 'exist', i.e. its `commonness` is `Nothing`. If empty nodes were actually removed from the trie, the query could return much sooner.

Comment: @jcsahnwaldt i agree completely

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can do something like this

```
def remove_string_helper(self, string, pnode, index):
    if pnode:
        flag = False
        if index < len(string):
            flag = self.remove_string_helper(string, pnode.childs.get(string[index]), index + 1)

        if index == len(string) and pnode.is_complete_word:
            pnode.is_complete_word = False
            return len(pnode.childs) == 0

        if flag:
            pnode.childs.pop(string[index])
            return len(self.childs) == 0

    return False

def remove_string(self, string):
    self.remove_string_helper(string, self.childs.get(string[0]), 1)
```